# Can a javascript function take down a VPS?

Tags: javascript, vps

Can a badly coded loop in javascript on a website consume so many server resources that it takes it down?

We have a VPS on our company i added a small code to scroll to a certain div on the theme and tied it to an click event. However the day i added that,  everything worked good untill the night when the server dropped and has been going down since like every day.

The hosting company says it was a space issue, but tracking down the thing  i found that code i added  that day. Is it possible that a simple scroll to when someone click on it can generate so much pressure on the VPS to take it down?

apparently i wrongly put it inside another code tied to another event.

I really  want to know if this is possible.

```
    $("#close-icon").click(function() {

if ($(".cresta-facebook-messenger-container").hasClass("open")) {
$('.cresta-facebook-messenger-box').hide('swift');
    $('#com-opt').show('swift');

}else{

    //nothing
}
    $("#show-mail-form").click(function() {

var scroll = accordion.top - 350 + (element * 90);
          jQuery('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: scroll });
          }, 310);

});

});
```

Comment: Depending on what the loop does? JS on a website runs on a client side, so if it never contacts the server (e.g. by making requests constantly such that the server is overwhelmed), the issue will be solely on the client side.

Comment: Can you show this code ? also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Is it a server side script ? like nodejs script ?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe based on _“small code to scroll to a certain div on the theme and tied it to an click event”_, I’m guessing client side.

Comment: I said it because it maybe had some ajax request to the backend, since you didn't showed anything...

Comment: @isaacgomez Formatting big blocks of code can be done by surrounding it with triple backticks (the key to the left of 1 on your keyboard), or by indenting it with four spaces.  I think you had used triple apostrophes.  I fixed it, I just wanted to explain so you can use the site more effectively.  Cheers.

Comment: I edited and added tue code to the question, as you can see i never perform any http request or else

Answer (score 1):

**If and only if the JavaScript loop makes a request to the backend for data.**

The code sample you've given does *not* make requests for data to the backend, so, no it will never take down any backend resources, such as a dedicated server or VPS. It will freeze the user's browser, which, at worst, could also freeze the user's local machine.

If the JavaScript does, however, make AJAX or API integration calls to the backend, then yes, certainly, badly written front-end code can overwhelm and take down a server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can even take down a dedicated server, not just a VPS. A few years back, we had an auth-related JS bug on our work's moodle login screen (wasn't my code), and it caused an infinite login loop that led moodle to spin up session after session after session until it exploded. The problem didn't surface on the dev or test servers, just with real users. That machine had to be rebooted, but a VPS could have easily been made practically unavailable even if it didn't go fully down...